# Carousel control; glyphicon-chevron not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a simple modal for my gallery. At the top of the page I'm implementing a slide carousel while at the bottom of it there are thumbnails of  gallery.

My problem is, while the slide carousel control button is working just fine, but the gallery wasn't. There supposed to be a Glyphicon of > and < but instead they're showing up as **Next>>** and **Prev<<** *Text*

My code is looks like this for the gallery :

```
<section class="bg-dark" id="gall">
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-picture-o wow bounceIn text-primary"></i> Workshop Gallery </h2>
            <hr class="primary">
        </div>
    </div>

      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/1.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/2.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/3.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/4.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/5.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/6.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/7.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/8.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/9.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/10.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/11.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/workshop/12.jpg">
        </li>
      </ul>

</div> <!-- /container -->


<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen force-fullscreen" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

</section>
```

My custom CSS are :

```
        /*Gallery */
    #gall ul {         
          padding:0 0 0 0;
          margin:0 0 0 0;
    }
    #gall ul li {     
          list-style:none;
          margin-bottom:25px;           
    }
     #gall ul li img {
          cursor: pointer;
    }
      #gall .modal-body {
          padding:5px !important;
    }
      #gall .modal-content {
          border-radius:0;
    }
      #gall .modal-dialog img {
          text-align:center;
          margin:0 auto;
    }
    #gall .controls{          
        width:50px;
        display:block;
        font-size:11px;
        padding-top:8px;
        font-weight:bold;          
    }

    #gall .next {
        float:right;
        text-align:right;
    }

    /* End of Gallery */

    /* Carousel */
    .main-container {
      padding: 40px 15px;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
          width: 70%;
          margin: auto;
    }
    .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .carousel-control.right,
    .carousel-control.left {
        background-image: none;
    }
    .carousel .item {
        min-height: 350px; 
        height: 100%;
        width:100%; 
    }
    .carousel-caption h3,
    .carousel .icon-container,
    .carousel-caption button {
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
    .carousel-caption h3 {
        padding: .5em;
    }
    .carousel .icon-container {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 25px;
        padding: 1em;
        text-align: center;

        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .carousel-caption button {
        border-color: #00bfff;
        margin-top: 1em; 
    }

    /* Animation delays */
    .carousel-caption h3:first-child {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
        animation-delay: 1s;
    }
    .carousel-caption h3:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
        animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    .carousel-caption button {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-delay: 3s;
    }
    /* End of Carousel */
```

And the javascript is this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
$('li img').on('click',function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive"/>';

    //start of new code new code
    var index = $(this).parent('li').index();   

    var html = '';
    html += img;                
    html += '<div style="height:25px;clear:both;display:block;">';
    html += '<a class="controls next" href="'+ (index+2) + '">next &raquo;</a>';
    html += '<a class="controls previous" href="' + (index) + '">&laquo; prev</a>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#myModal').modal();
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html(html);
        //new code
        $('a.controls').trigger('click');
    })
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');
    });

  });   
})


$(document).on('click', 'a.controls', function(){
var index = $(this).attr('href');
var src = $('ul.row li:nth-child('+ index +') img').attr('src');             

$('.modal-body img').attr('src', src);

var newPrevIndex = parseInt(index) - 1; 
var newNextIndex = parseInt(newPrevIndex) + 2; 

if($(this).hasClass('previous')){               
    $(this).attr('href', newPrevIndex); 
    $('a.next').attr('href', newNextIndex);
}else{
    $(this).attr('href', newNextIndex); 
    $('a.previous').attr('href', newPrevIndex);
}

var total = $('ul.row li').length + 1; 
//hide next button
if(total === newNextIndex){
    $('a.next').hide();
}else{
    $('a.next').show()
}            
//hide previous button
if(newPrevIndex === 0){
    $('a.previous').hide();
}else{
    $('a.previous').show()
}


return false;
});
```

And heres the screenshot :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgbmi.jpg)

I think its something wrong with the carousel control? Any advice will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Javascript, the appended controls for the navigation do not have the proper glyphicon classes.

It should be:

```
var html = '';
    html += img;                
    html += '<div style="height:25px;clear:both;display:block;">';
    html += '<a class="controls next glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" href="'+ (index+2) + '"></a>';
    html += '<a class="controls prev glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left   " href="' + (index) + '"></a>';
    html += '</div>';
```

I'd recommend adding a custom class to the two control classes to make sure the font size is decent.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you very much. and yes, I guess I need to resize them :)

Comment: One more little thing... Is there a way to float it in the middle of the picture, not at the bottom of it. So they should be floating centered in the right and left side of the pic...

Comment: If you'd like to do that, I'd change the code so that it's the appended left/right links are in the same row as the img and get rid of `'div style height:25px…`. And you are adding the first link then the img variable and then the second link. One way to center the links is using flexbox on the `#gall .modal-body` class with `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center`.